# Trying to filter columns using the wildcard *

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a new dataframe object from an existing dataset that contains multiple similar columns that start with "shape_" I am trying to use the wildcard (*) but I am getting an error.

```
new_df = df[['date', 'lat', 'long', 'shape_*']]
```

from all the examples I have seen this should work but I am getting the error:

> KeyError: "['shape_*'] not in index"

Comment: Can you reference one of "*all the examples*" that you have seen in which such an indexing would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html):

```
cols = list(df.filter(like='shape_').columns)
new_df = df[['date', 'lat', 'long']+cols]
```

Or with a regex:

```
cols = list(df.filter(regex='^shape_.*').columns)
new_df = df[['date', 'lat', 'long']+cols]
```